# How insert HTML FORM in RSS

Tags: html, forms, rss

I need insert HTML FORM in RSS. I make it, but in any RSS Readers this form don't show.

I wanna ask — may be RSS Readers don't work with html?

Comment: RSS is not made for anything else but reading data, especially not for submitting forms. Have a read on what RSS is and find another way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds are basically XML text and RSS readers just display the info in a formatted version. They will not render any HTML codes like web browsers do.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought so. Thank you.